# IOS - Facebook how to invite friends to download app?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an Ios app , i'm trying to implement this flow:

User click a button->a list of my facebook friends appears-> i select one or more friends-> to each of this friends the app sends an invite to download the app from store-> i count and save locally the number of friends invited.

I have read documentation and the FBSDKAppInviteDialog seems to be the right choose. I have implement this solution and then i have discover this:

- In ios 9 i can't switch in the fb app during the login
- I can't know how many friends i have invited
- The safariviewcontroller can't dismiss after an invite
- The documentation is invisible

and maybe so on...

I have removed this FBSDKAppInviteDialog, it can't be a solution.

After hours i'm very frustrating, anyway i have see the candy crush app. It can send invites in in web browser,facebook app,mobile browers and it can select multiple facebook friends. Anyone know how achive the same result? I can replicate with Graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In ios 9 i can't switch in the fb app during the login

This is expected behavior, on iOS9, the Facebook SDK will fallback to a `SFSafariViewController` based approach for most of the dialogs

---

> I can't know how many friends i have invited

As far as I know, the dialogs never supported this.

---

> The safariviewcontroller can't dismiss after an invite

This seems to be a functionality `SFSafariViewController` doesn't support (dismissing it from within the loaded page).

---

> The documentation is invisible

The documentation for the FBSDKAppInviteDialog works fine for me (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios). If this is not working for you, it'd be a good idea to file a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs so Facebook can look into it and fix any bugs that might be present